# How to check if keyboard is connected or or not and use it if it is connected during runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, libusb, opensuse, input-devices

So I have a QT project in which I want to check if a keyboard is connected. In case it's not connected I want to be able to still use it if it is connected during the program is running. I looked around and found a few libraries that might be suitable but I am not sure if they can do what I want. Libraries in question: `libinput`, `libusb` or `Solid` with KDE. My question is, will one of these libraries do what I want it to do or is it something completly different? If it is one of the above libraries than any examples would help a ton because I can't really get anything out of the documentation. I should probably also mention that I use a linux, or to be more exact openSUSE Leap 15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well turns out it wasn't as complicated as I thought and none of the libraries that I talked about are needed. Here is my solution, in case any one in the future is looking for something similar.

scanner.h

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QSocketNotifier>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

class Scanner : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static Scanner* getInstance(void);
    int saveInCorrectFormat(int code);

protected:
    void run() override;

signals:
    void ChipScanned(QString rfid);

private slots:
    void handleNotification(int socket);
    void checkScannerData();

private:
    Scanner(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Scanner();

    void initScanner(void);

    static Scanner* sInstance;
    QString defaultPath = "/dev/input/event2";
    QString rfid;
    QTimer* sCheckScanner;
    QFile *sScannerFile;
    QSocketNotifier *sNotifier;
    int fd;
    bool notificationEnabled;
    struct input_event event;
    int RFID[10];
    int i = 0;
    int buffer = 0;
};

#endif // SCANNER_H
```

scanner.cpp

```
#include "scanner.h"

Scanner* Scanner::sInstance = new Scanner();

Scanner* Scanner::getInstance(void){
    return sInstance;
}

Scanner::Scanner(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent){
    moveToThread(this);
    start();
}

Scanner::~Scanner(){

}

void Scanner::run(){
    initScanner();
    QThread::exec();
}

/**
 * @brief Scanner::initScanner
 * initialize the timer to check up on the keyboard event file
 */
void Scanner::initScanner(void){
    notificationEnabled = false;
    sScannerFile = new QFile(defaultPath);

    sCheckScanner = new QTimer(this);
    sCheckScanner->setInterval(100);
    sCheckScanner->setSingleShot(false);
    connect(sCheckScanner, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkScannerData()));
    sCheckScanner->start();
}

/**
 * @brief Scanner::checkScannerData
 * check if the keyboard is connected or not
 * if it is connected, activate event handling
 */
void Scanner::checkScannerData(){
    if(sScannerFile->exists()){
        if(notificationEnabled){
            return;
        }

        fd = open(defaultPath.toUtf8().data(), O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        if(-1 != fd){
            sNotifier = new QSocketNotifier(fd, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
            connect(sNotifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(handleNotification(int)));
            qDebug() << "Scanner connected";
            notificationEnabled = true;
        }
    }else{
        if(notificationEnabled){
            sNotifier->setEnabled(false);
            disconnect(sNotifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(handleNotification(int)));
            delete sNotifier;
            close(fd);
            qDebug() << "Scanner disconnect";
            notificationEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Scanner::handleNotification
 * check if the keyboard is still connected or if the event was the disconnect
 * if still connected than read the data and save it
 * @param socket
 */
void Scanner::handleNotification(int socket){
    if(!sScannerFile->exists()){
        if(notificationEnabled){
            sNotifier->setEnabled(false);
            disconnect(sNotifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(handleNotification(int)));
            delete sNotifier;
            close(fd);
            qDebug() << "Scanner disconnect";
            notificationEnabled = false;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(read(fd, &event, sizeof(event)) == sizeof(event)){
        if(event.type != EV_SYN){
            if(event.value == 1 && event.code != 28){
                RFID[i] = saveInCorrectFormat(event.code);
                rfid.append(QString("%1").arg(saveInCorrectFormat(event.code)));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(rfid.size() == 10){
        buffer++;
        if(buffer == 10){
            emit ChipScanned(rfid);
            qDebug() << rfid;
            i = 0;
            buffer = 0;
            rfid.clear();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Scanner::saveInCorrectFormat
 * correct the raw data in the it's right format
 * @param code
 * current data to convert
 * @return
 * converted data
 */
int Scanner::saveInCorrectFormat(int code){
    switch(code){
    case 11:
        return 0;
    case 28:
        return -1;
    default:
        return code-1;
    }
}
```

A few extra infos:
My device isn't really a keyboard but the input is handled as if it is a keyboard that's why I have to make a few tweaks with the raw data before it is in the expected format. Anyone else most likely won't need those tweaks, like `int saveInCorrectFormat` or the `if` condition after reading the data. I believe this code is rather universal which means changing the `defaultPath` and making a few tweaks while reading the raw data will probably make it possible to use it for other devices as well.